# Do Node and Express validate certain request fields?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, security, express

I am questioning whether it is required to validate fields like `req.ip` or `req.path` server-side.
It boils down to the question: Is it possible for the client to set something like `.set('Remote-Addr', <Malicious JavaScript>)` and it successfully being propagated to my Node or Express middleware?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be doing an `eval(req.ip)` if that's what you're wondering about. But using the string in req.ip as just a string should be safe  There are lots of ways for a client to spoof their real IP (such as proxies) so you can never assume `req.ip` is the actual client IP and there is no way for Express/Node to validate what the real client IP is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The malicious Javascript was just an example. The concrete use case is that we are logging the ip into a database and want to make sure only valid ip's are  being inserted. So from your example I suppose that express and node both don't validate the request fields, right?

Comment: There is no way to validate source IP, particular when proxies are involved.  In the proxy case, a chain of IP addresses is supposed to be put in http headers, but that can certainly be faked so what express thinks is the original IP cannot be trusted.  It is likely accurate, but not guaranteed accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to validate source IP, particular when proxies are involved. In the proxy case, a chain of IP addresses is supposed to be put in http headers, but that can certainly be faked so what express thinks is the original IP cannot be trusted. It is likely accurate, but not guaranteed accurate.

`req.path` is entirely local and does not involve any client headers and is not subject to any client spoofing.  It just comes from the actual HTTP request URL  that arrives at your server.  The only way it wouldn't be the same as the actual request URL is if you were using a mount point for routers in which case the mount point part of the path will have been removed by express. Or perhaps if your own middleware attempted to mess with it.

Comment: Thanks alot. You are of course completely right and I should've been more clear in my question. It's not about validating the semantic behind the IP information (i.e. whether it is correct) but rather its formal representation since we are logging these into the database. For example: Someone spoofs the IP header to contain some JavaScript. We save it into the database and later (assuming integrity of our db) output it to the browser where it is executed. Your notes about `req.path` were helpful. Thanks. And since you indirectly answered my question in the comments I'll mark this as answer.

Comment: @FunkyPeanut - If you put that actual use case (inserting the ip address back into a web page) into your question, you would have gotten a much more targeted answer.  Please always describe the real problem rather than make the question generic.  We are so much more on-target helpful when you describe the actual problem you are concerned about.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I'll keep that in mind, thanks.

Comment: @FunkyPeanut - If you were going to insert the IP address back into a web page, you should sanitize it to make sure it does not contain any script tags or insert it in a way that scripts are not evaluated.